# Sorting using comparator in Priority queue but not getting it right

Tags: java

```
PriorityQueue<Player> playerQueue = new PriorityQueue<Player>(30,
                new Comparator<Player>( ) {
                    // overriding the compare method
                    public int compare(Player i, Player j) {
                        return (int)i.playerPrice() < (int)j.playerPrice() ? -1 : ((int)i.playerPrice() == (int)j.playerPrice()) ? 0 : 1;
                    }
                }
          );

        for(Player a:XMLParserViaSax.getListOfPlayers()){
            System.out.println(a.getName()+ "-->"+a.playerPrice());
        }

        for(Player player:XMLParserViaSax.getListOfPlayers()){
            playerQueue.add(player);
        }
        //playerQueue.addAll(XMLParserViaSax.getListOfPlayers());

        System.out.println("**************************");
        for(Player j:playerQueue){
            System.out.println(j.getName()+ "-->"+j.playerPrice());
        }
```

I am trying to sort the Player by playerprice,I don't have any variable as playerprice in Player class.playerPrice() is a method which will calculate price of a player.so now when I am trying to sort these Player Objects it is giving me a random order.

Do I need to have one playerprice private member inside my player class ?
'
Player class is like this :

```
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private int battingStrength;
    private int bowlingStrength;
    private int fieldingStrength;
    private int keepingStrength;
    private int jerseyNumber;

    public int playerStrength() {
    return AuctionPlayerHelper.calculateStrength(this);
    }

    public boolean canKeepWickets() {
    return (keepingStrength == 10);
    }

    public boolean isForeignPlayer(){
    return AuctionPlayerHelper.isForeignPlayer(this.jerseyNumber);
    }

    public double playerPrice() {
     return AuctionPlayerHelper.calculatePrice(this);

    }

    //getters,setters
}
```

'

Comment: `for(Player j:playerQueue)` does not guarantee order.

Comment: even taking a member variable as playerPrice is not helping me..I am still getting the order as random ?? Please help!

Comment: We've explained why it doesn't work. What more help do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Note from the [PriorityQueue API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

So iterating through the Queue as you are doing will not be in "order".

The priority ordering becomes evident when you *remove* the head from the queue such as when you call `poll()` on the queue.

Comment: At that point what might well be wanted is replacing the PriorityQueue with a TreeSet, which would yield the desired traversal order, and the players are presumably unique anyway so a set would be okay.

Comment: Thankyou will try the same and check.